# Why Plus operator does not work on integers in Alloy?

Tags: alloy

below alloy code is for 8Queens problem
I do not know why plus operator and minus operator does not work correctly
so after execution there are queens in same diagonal
Moreover I am face to this error when use plus and minus operator between 2 #
for example :
    #q1.row+#q2.col-#q1.col != #q2.row

thanks for any response
best regards

---

here that's 8Queens code:

```
sig Queens{
row:Int,
col:Int
}
{row>=0 and row <#Queens and col>=0 and col<#Queens}

pred nothreat(q1,q2 : Queens) {
   q1.row != q2.row 
   and q1.col != q2.col 
   and q1.row+q2.col-q1.col != q2.row
   and q1.row-q2.col+q1.col != q2.row
}

pred valid { 
all q1,q2 : Queens |   q1 != q2 => nothreat[q1, q2]
 }
fact card {#Queens =8}
run valid for 8 Queens, 8 Int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `plus` and `minus` functions instead (e.g., `q1.row.plus[q2.col].minus[q1.col]`), because `+` is always treated as set union, and `-` as set difference.